# symfony5 service - how to inject session and user without the ContainerInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have this deprecation message:

> Since symfony/dependency-injection 5.1: The
> "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface" autowiring
> alias is deprecated. Define it explicitly in your app if you want to
> keep using it.

From threads such as this [Symfony: Explicit define Container in Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860123/symfony-explicit-define-container-in-service) I understand that the long-term solution is to stop using the ContainerInterface all together in my services.

My services.yaml looks like this:

```
parameters:
    #locale: en
    basepath: '%env(basepath)%'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    globalHelper:
        class: App\Service\globalHelper
        public: false
```

The service in question (globalHelper) looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface as EntityManager;

class globalHelper {

    private $container;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(Container $container, EntityManager $em) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

I only user the container to fetch session variables like this

```
$this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

And to get the current user (security context) like this

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Can I get these sub-components of the container separately instead? What component then would I inject to access these two parts (session and user) respectively?

--------------- Addition --------------

According to Alexis' suggestion below I modified the head of the file with

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

//use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface as EntityManager;

class globalHelper {

    //private $container;
    private $requestStack;
    private $security;
    private $em;

    //public function __construct(Container $container, RequestStack $requestStack, Security $security, EntityManager $em) {
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, Security $security, EntityManager $em) {
        //$this->container = $container;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

then replaced

```
$this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

with

```
$this->requestStack->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

and get this error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getSession" of class
> "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack".

if I instead to this:

```
$this->requestStack->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
> "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack". Did you mean to call
> e.g. "getCurrentRequest", "getMasterRequest" or "getParentRequest"?

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?  The [RequestStack::getSession](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation) method was introduced in 5.3.  Before that you would typehint against the SessionInterface.  Or use `$this->requestStack->getMainRequest()->getSession()`

Comment: You can automatically inject a custom container with some services of interest by implementing `ServiceSubscriberInterface`. See AbstractController`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6c8c93d542103656a37b8cda1d293c29d083ed51/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php#L85) for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it’s not mandatory to declare your service help with

```
autoconfigure: true
```

Then you must inject

`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack`

and make

```
$requestStack->getSession()
```

Here's the docs

https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html

For user you inject

`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security`

and make

```
$security->getUser()
```

Here's the docs

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#fetching-the-user-from-a-service

**-- EDIT --**

Prio symfony 5.3 session can directly be injected with

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface
```

It's depreciated after. Here's the blog post :

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation

Comment: Thank you, I tried but I think I'm missing something. See my addition to original question.

Comment: What is your exact Symfony version ? Prior 5.3 you must inject SessionInterface instead of RequestStack and you'll get session directly

Comment: See @Cerad comment above. The request stack is, well... a stack. An array that contains all subrequests during this lifecycle, so you have to get the current one before getting the session.

Comment: I'm working upwards =) was on 5.2 when I posted the question, currently on 5.3 and with 5.3 your solution works!

Comment: @msg Just for info, RequestStack::getSession was added in 5.3 so no need for a request.  The link I posted in my other comment shows some of the reasoning.

Comment: @Cerad Hmmm, interesting. I always `getCurrentRequest` from the stack first, didn't realize there's a `getSession` method in the stack. Maybe I got confused by [this comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/41120#issuecomment-833664994) about the session scoping and the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Using symfony 6.2, you can also add this on your `service.yml`:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface:
  factory: "@=service('request_stack').getCurrentRequest()?.getSession()"
```

It can return `null` value